# Comparing parts of strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-comparison, text-comparison, vba

I am trying to compare two cells with similar texts
eg: 
Cell A1: original_content 
Cell B1: orig_cont

I want to be able to compare A1 and B1 and get the comparison result to be "TRUE"

I am trying to use wild card in MATCH function after splitting the cell (text to columns), but I want to depend on using a formula.

Comment: Look up Fuzzy-Lookup.

Comment: What language? In excel formulas?

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for the suggestion. It works.

Comment: @Rohlex32 yes. Using excel formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this website and doing some sort of 'OR' statement in the excel formula
(https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text)

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1)) OR ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1))
```